# error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick - Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qtquick2, linux-mint

I installed Qt Creator via the Software Manager on *Linux Mint 18 (x86_64)*.
I made a few sample projects, and some dependencies/packages/libraries/whatever were missing, so I installed the via apt.
I made a QtQuick application and in Issues there is an error message saying:

```
 error: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick
```

I read that there is some libraries to build and link, but I don't know where to find them.

Comment: wow you don't need to shout (use CAPS). maybe check here if this is related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/508503/whats-the-development-package-for-qt5-in-14-04

Comment: Sorry for the shouting, hope it didn't hurt your eardrums ;-)

Comment: Btw, I read something related to the askubuntu post, maye that will fix it. I will check it out.

Comment: Actually, it worked! Thank you very much, @Hayt

Answer (score 92, accepted):

According to Hayt's answer (and the askubuntu post), I had to install the  `qtdeclarative5-dev` package.

Comment: Also solves similar 'error: Unknown module in QT: quick'

Comment: On Fedora Linux, it's `qt5-qtdeclarative-devel`

Comment: Thanks!
I had to install qtquickcontrols2-5-dev as well to make it work for me.